# Efficient solution to this scheduling problem or integer optimization problem

Tags: optimization, dynamic-programming, combinatorics, scheduling, integer-programming

**Context:** Suppose I have a matrix $P_k\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ that evolves in time $k$ according to
$$
P_{k+1} = H_{\sigma(k)}^TP_kH_{\sigma(k)}
$$
where $H_{\sigma(k)}\in\{H_1,\dots,H_L\}$, $H_i\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ are some given matrices and $\sigma(k)\in\{1,\dots,L\}$ is a scheduling signal. My goal is to obtain $\sigma(0),\dots,\sigma(N-1)$ such that
$$
J = \sum_{k=0}^N \text{trace}(P_{k})
$$
is minimized, provided some initial positive definite matrix $P_0$.

**My naive attempt:** Up to now, I have only been able to solve this by enumerating all possible combinations of $[\sigma(0),\dots,\sigma(N-1)]\in\{1,\dots,L\}^N$, compute the cost for each of them and choose the one with the least cost. However, as you can see, this solution is not very efficient and can only be used for small $N$. In fact, this solution has complexity that grows as $L^N$.

**The question(s):**

- Do you think there is a better way to solve this problem, say by a polynomial time algorithm, or using dynamic programming to find a more efficient (still exponential) solution?
- Do you think there is a way to find an approximate solution to this problem which can be obtained in polynomial time?
- Do any of the previous questions answers change if we change (in "high level") $P_{k+1} = F(P_k,\sigma(k))$ for some nonlinear function $F(\bullet,\sigma(k))$.

Any ideas, suggestions or references for me to read are appreciated.

Comment: Can you give us some concrete values for the parameters?    e.g., typical values of $n$ and $N$ and $L$?

Comment: Do the matrices $H_1,\dots,H_L$ have some structure so that the number of possible values for $P_k$ is a lot less than $L^k$?

Comment: Do you require an algorithm that gives you the global minimum, or are you interested in algorithms that don't give the absolute optimum and trade off a suboptimal solution in exchange for more computational efficiency?

Comment: $L=2$ is a good starting point, but $N>100$ is of interest. The matrices $H_i$ do not have structure to simplify the possible values for $P_k$. I am not interested in the global optimum. I prefer focusing on on suboptimal solutions. Thanks

Comment: I forgot. $n=2$ is also of interest.

Comment: Can the trace go negative?

Comment: I don't think so. Since the initial condition $P_0$, is positive definite I think all $P_k$ will be positive (semi) definite at least. So the traces are all non-negative, right?

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_matrix#Trace) says that $\mathrm{trace}(MN) \ge 0$ when *both* $M$ and $N$ are positive semidefinite, but doesn't explicitly guarantee that $\mathrm{trace}(M^TNM) \ge 0$ when just $N$ is, which I think is what we need here.

Comment: I agree. we may  assume negative traces too then. Thanks

Comment: Well, it's possible that the trace is nevertheless guaranteed to remain nonnegative in your case, and I think it would be worth investigating whether this is true, since I think it may make the problem easier: It should then be possible to get the trace as low as possible, and thereafter choose matrices $H_i$ as close to $I$ as possible. As a first step, do you see negative traces in any of your examples?

Comment: I have taken a look at my examples, and I can see that the traces seem to be always positive. The equation for $P_{k+1}$ comes from a covariance propagation formula, so I might be able to justify that formally later.